# Show more/View all items in a recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

- I am implementing a `Recyclerview` which displays 3 items and a button.
- If user taps on ***View all*** button for list should *expand* as shown in the below image:

[image]

- I have created a simple `Recyclerview` that shows list item but how can I achieve **View all** functinality as I am confused.

Comment: So you recyclerView contains only "Social Accounts" (Button with View All), "Contact" (Button with View All), etc? Or how's your recyclerView? How is your recyclerView Item? You need an expandable recycler view?

Comment: So you have Item1(Instagram), Item2(TikTok), Item3(Twitter) and last item is a button (View All), no?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Yes right.

Answer (score 3):

Solution idea:

1. You can put the viewAll-button outside of the RecyclerView, but below it inside of the parent your RecyclerView is in to make the logic easier. (see comments for more information)
2. Create a public boolean in your adapter called "viewAll".
3. Set a click listener for the viewAllButton that:

   - executes `viewAllButton.setText(adapter.viewAll ? "View all" : "View less");`
   - sets `adapter.viewAll` to `!adapter.viewAll`
   - calls `recyclerView.requestLayout();` to update the UI.
4. In your `getChildrenCount()`, `return viewAll ? yourViewCount : 3;`.

Comment: I would still recommend keeping the button inside the adapter, I don't see the point of moving it out.

Comment: @HenryTwist I thought it would be easier to leave it out, because if you leave it in, the 4th child can either be the viewAll-button or another button, which is hard to program in my opinion.

Comment: Well I don't think it's really as difficult as you're making out. If the item is last, it's the button, otherwise it's not. You could even use a `ConcatAdapter` if you wanted to avoid implementing any logic.

Answer (score 1):

> In your activity/fragment where you're fetching details and passing into list. Do the same

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    
    if(modelList.size>3){
        YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(modelList.subList(0,3));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
        viewAllBtn.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
        viewAllBtn.setOnClickListener(v->{
            YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(modelList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
            viewAllBtn.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
        });
    }else{
        YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(modelList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
        viewAllBtn.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
    }
```

This worked in my case